# Issue with e(fx)clipse plugin on OS X Yosemite

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, javafx

I installed the e(fx)clipse plugin on OS X Yosemite. When I startup eclipse I get the following error message:

> You are not running your eclipse instance with Java8. The JavaFX
>   tooling is disabled because of this.Make Java8 the default system java
>   or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install.

Now, I read through all the answers similar to this post but they are either out of date or unanswered. I tried downloading Kepler SR2 but it says its not supported with my eclipse(Luna 4.4.1). 
How can I enable JavaFX tooling ?

Comment: @tnw, what about this question?

Comment: The message you get looks pretty clear to me. You need to be using a Java 8 JRE/JDK to run Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 I have all that installed. Thats why I'm still trying to figure out whats going on.. ?